# SQL Server Express backup script

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-express, sqlcmd

I was able to perform backup for my SQL Server Express using this command at the command prompt:

```
SQLCMD -E -S testing\SQLEXPRESS –Q "BACKUP DATABASE testing3 TO DISK='C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.bak'"
```

When I want to create a batch script using the command above  in order to create a task scheduler to perform auto backup, it shows error as below:

Here is the batch code:

```
echo off

c: \
CD "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn"
SQLCMD -E -S testing\SQLEXPRESS –Q "BACKUP DATABASE testing3 TO DISK='C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.bak';"
```

I didn't put exit at bottom of it because I want to verify whether the command successfully run or not.

ERROR:

> Sqlcmd: 'ûQ "BACKUP DATABASE testing3 TO DISK='C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.bak' ': Unexpected argument. Enter '-?' for help.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT : I solve it by giving a semi column at the end and type it one by one instead of copy paste it

Comment: Could you show the bash script code?

Comment: Hi @gotqn , I have put the script code above

Comment: Could you put in quotes this `testing\SQLEXPRESS` - make it `"testing\SQLEXPRESS"`?

Comment: Hi @gotqn, I have put the quotes as mentioned by you and it still come out the same error

Comment: The `ûQ ` characters in the `Sqlcmd: 'ûQ "BACKUP DATABASE testing3 TO DISK=...` error message look like a UTF-8 Byte Order Mark. Did you get the error in the question by running `sqlcmd.exe -i SomeFileNameOfYourChoosing.sql` where the .sql file was UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: That is not bash.  Batch maybe.  Make sure the `-` before the `Q` is really a minus.  Windows has this tendency of replacing the `-` with a slightly longer character that looks like a `-`, but is not the same char.